# Как добавить станции метро через google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api

Добрый день, использую api google maps, стилизовал все как надо, только вот вопрос, как добавить что бы показывались станции метро а так же где посмотреть все доступнные опции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-transit

```
var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
transitLayer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените **[библиотеку Places JavaScript of Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)**. Чтобы использовать функции из этой библиотеки, необходимо предварительно загрузить ее с помощью параметра libraries в загрузочном URL-адресе Google Maps API:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

С помощью этой службы Places можно выполнять четыре вида поиска:

- **[Поиск мест поблизости](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)** – возвращает список близлежащих мест в
  зависимости от местоположения пользователя.
- **[Текстовый поиск](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests)** – возвращает список близлежащих мест в зависимости от введенной текстовой строки, например: "Станции метро".
- **[Массовый поиск](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#radar_search_requests)** – возвращает большой список мест в указанном радиусе
  поиска, но с меньшим уровнем детализации по сравнению с поиском мест
  поблизости и текстовым поиском.
- **[Запросы данных о месте](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details)** – возвращают более подробную информацию о
  конкретном месте, в том числе отзывы пользователей.

### Поиск мест поблизости

Поиск мест поблизости позволяет находить места в указанной области по ключевому слову или по типу. Поиск мест поблизости всегда должен включать местоположение, которое можно указать одним из следующих двух способов:

-- параметр **LatLngBounds**;

-- область внутри окружности, определяемой свойством **location**, которое задает центр окружности в виде объекта LatLng, и радиусом окружности в метрах.

Пример, ближайшие станции метро:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ближайшие станции метро</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>

      var map;
      var infowindow;

      function initMap() {
        var moskva = {lat:55.7479275, lng:37.6393378};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: moskva,
          zoom: 11
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: moskva,
          radius: 10000,
          type: ['subway_station']
        }, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Для определения координат центра вы можете использовать этот инструмент [**iTouchMap**](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html). Обратите внимание, что параметр type имеет содержание ***subway_station***. Смотрите **[список типов мест](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types)**.

### Текстовый поиск

Служба текстового поиска Google Places – это веб-служба, которая возвращает информацию о местах на основе введенной фразы, например "пиццерия Химки" или "магазины обуви рядом с г. Иваново". Служба возвращает список мест, соответствующий текстовой строке запроса и установленному предпочтительному местоположению. Ответ на поисковый запрос будет содержать список мест. Обязательный параметр запроса **query** – текстовая строка, по которой выполняется поиск, например "ресторан". Служба Places возвращает подходящие варианты на основе этой строки. Результаты сортируются по релевантности. Этот параметр не обязателен, если в поисковом запросе также используется параметр type. Пример для станций метро в Москве:

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var moskva = new google.maps.LatLng(lat:55.7479275, lng:37.6393378);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: moskva,
      zoom: 11
    });

  var request = {
    location: moskva,
    radius: '10000',
    query: 'subway_station'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Также вы можете использовать **[слои KML GeoRSS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer)**.